# tinyurl api using curl returning blank

Tags: api, curl, tinyurl

When I am trying below Code,l Its returning me Blank. Any Clue what could be the reason ?

> ```
> <?php
>
> function tiny_url($url){
>
> $ch = curl_init();
> $timeout = 5; 
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://tinyurl . com/api-create.php?url='.$url);
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
> $data = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
> return $data;
> }
>
>
> echo tiny_url("www.google.com");
>
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Is it normal to have spaces in your URL ? `http://tinyurl . com/api-create.php`

Comment: No but stackflow was not allowing me to submit url , so added a white space

Comment: you're getting an (uncaught) error somewhere and you have display_errors=Off in php.ini and you're not checking your error logs. (either that or you have error_reporting=0 in php.ini)

Comment: I did check my Error Log and Nothing there. May be my hosting server issues ?